# LXD container on GlusterFS

Tags: lxc, glusterfs

I'm trying to add a container created with LXC (v2.0) into a GlusterFS (v3.12) mount. So I tried to mount /var/lib/lxd/containers prior to creating the container, obviously I got the error message saying that directory is not the same filesystem of /root (which is Btrfs).

First, is this a good idea? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post as it gives instructions...

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-mount-glusterfs-volumes-inside-lxclxd-linux-containers/

Comment: I'm looking for the opposite. LXC in GlusterFS and not GlusterFS inside LXC.